# How to read the csv file having more than 20k records using Power automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, csv

I am having the CSV file in my SharePoint library. Using power automate trying to read the csv data and will update the values to the SharePoint list.

Initially with 200 rows the flow ran successfully. After that I am trying to read the csv it having more than 6k records and I was getting below error.

> Unable to process template language expressions in action 'CSV_Data' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'uriComponent' was invoked with invalid parameters. The parameter at index '0' cannot be converted to URI component.'.

to get the csv data from SharePoint I am using "Get file content" action and then having the CSV data in array format. Find the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To read the csv file having more than 20k records using Power automate, you should use the HTTP action with user credentials.

Reference: [Different ways of getting Excel data using Power Automate](https://anoopt.medium.com/different-ways-of-getting-excel-data-using-power-automate-e21292b1d02a)